# Excel Power Query and Pivot Tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

In the Excel Power Query Editor, I have a field whose values I'm converting. The code looks like this

```
if [Field] = "a" then "abcd" else if [Field] = "b" then "efg" 
else if [Field]="  " then "  "
```

The problem is that [Field] could have just 2 spaces, like this "  ", and I want to keep those two spaces, but when I see that field in a pivot table the spaces are gone and the field value is essentially blank. Pivot tables seem to trim the field's value. How can I prevent that trimming so that the two-space value is retained?

Comment: Not exactly getting your issue. The code you are using would never generate two spaces for that column. If you want to preserve the spaces then test for the spaces and perhaps do ="space" then later on replace that in the picot table by typing over

Comment: I updated my question to make it more explicit. Assigning two spaces does not translate to two spaces in the related pivot table because the pivot table field implicitly trims the value. Further, I cannot type over the field in the pivot table. Use of a measure did not help. All that I want to do is to preserve the two spaces as the value.

Comment: Can you show your sample input data, full code and expected output as it isn't clear to me either. If spaces are being swallowed, you can use Character.FromNumber and use a unicode replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ANSI character code 160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/character-set-128255) can do this for you. AKA "the evil char", sometimes cheats us by insisting on being where it shouldn't be (in place of a blank). Then create a variable called, say, CharCode160, and assign the character Chr(160) to it. This is the M code to guide you through your solution.

Please note that the source table is named "Table1" and the field involved has the column title "TheField".

It will be useful to add a routine - or modified code - that counts how many blanks there are in the field, to make the correct replacement.

```
let
CharCode160 = Character.FromNumber(160),
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TheField", type text}}),
    #"Conditional Column Added" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [TheField] = "a" then "abcd" else if [TheField] = "b" then "efg" else if [TheField] = "  " then CharCode160 & CharCode160 else null)
in
    #"Conditional Column Added"
```

Answer (score 0):

If character does not necessarily need to be `space` character then you could use other unicode characters that look like `space`:
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs

For example: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2000

You just copy character and paste it to PQ.